# How to create string variable referencing other string variables in Stata?

Tags: stata

I currently have 2 variables, `state` and `year`, into which I wish to convert into 1 variable, `stateyear`.

I want the `stateyear` variable to have values in the following form: `state_year` (e.g. `Texas_1962`).

How can I reference the values in the `state` and `year` variables to create the new `stateyear` variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That could be

```
 gen state_year = state + "_" + string(year)
```

where I am assuming that `year` is numeric. Or it could be

```
 egen state_year = concat(state year), p(_)
```

which takes care of any type conversions needed.

Or it could be

```
 egen state_year = group(state year), label
```

which doesn't give you a connecting underscore. That raises a key point: why you do think you need that underscore? It will just look ugly on graphs or tables. If spaces are (thought to be) a problem, what about "North Carolina_2013", and so forth?

For a miniature review of this question, see http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0034

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example:

```
// create some example data
clear
input ///
str13 state      int year
"Noord-Holland"  1962
"Zuid-Holland"   1963
"Utrecht"        1964
"Zeeland"        1965
"Noord-Brabant"  1966
"Limburg"        1967
"Gelderland"     1968
"Flevoland"      1969
"Overijsel"      1970
"Drente"         1971
"Friesland"      1972
"Groningen"      1973
end

// create the variable
gen str18 state_year = state + "_" + string(year)

// admire the result
list
```

If the `+` operator appears between two string, then it means that Stata has to concatenate the two strings.

So, the part `state + "_"` means add the string `"_"` after the content of the string variable `state`. To make sure that `+` also means concatenate for the part `"_" + string(year)`, I used the `string()` function, which turns the numeric values of the variable `year` into strings.

The `str18` part means that you want the variable `state_year` to be a string with 18 characters. This works for the Dutch states in this examples, but you will need to count the number of characters in the state with the longest name and add 5 to that, to determine the maximum length of the string in your case. Say that number is 21, then you need to replace `str18` with `str21`

Answer (score 1):

One addition to Nick's solution. If the state variable is stored as numeric with value labels (e.g. `1 "Alabama" 2 "Alaska"` etc.) I believe you will also need to specify the `decode` option, thus to convert the labels into strings:

```
 egen state_year = concat(state year), p(_) decode
```